# Calling a function when an activity is returned to from fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have a fragment that I call like so from my activities `onCreate`

```
android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

DeviceControlFragment newFragment = new DeviceControlFragment();

newFragment.device = device;
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.content_frame, newFragment)
        .commit();
```

In the fragment I can either pop the back stack or hit back like so:

```
getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
```

OR

```
getActivity().onBackPressed();
```

But I need something in the activity so that I know we have returned there, is there something similar to `onActivityResult` that I can override in the activity to know when the fragment has been 'finished'

Comment: So you launch a fragment in your activity's `onCreate` and want to know when the fragment has been popped? The activity lifecycle is closely tied to the fragment, so if you call `onBackPressed` or `popBackStack` manually, then you know when you are popping the fragment already right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare a interface inside fragment and implement it in your activity and send response to activity inside `onDetach()`,`onDestroy` or `onPaused` method of fragment,  any of them which suits you. I will prefer `onDetach` or `onDestroy`

Here is sample for that:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }

    private Test mListener;

    public interface Test{
        void imLeavingYou();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        mListener = (Test) context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        if(mListener != null){
            mListener.imLeavingYou();
        }
    }
}
```

And in your `Activity` do this:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyFragment.Test {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
    }

    @Override
    public void imLeavingYou() {
        // Okay thanks for informing
    }
}
```

Comment: I hadn't considered using an interface in that way, I like it, will give it a crack now

Comment: This solution is good as you said you want to inform activity from a specific fragment.

Comment: Yeah I have other interfaces on the app but they are used app wide, I like this as it's specific to that fragment

Comment: Its concept of OOP,"Information Hiding".  We should declare interfaces inside class who act on that interface.....

Comment: To make it more generic you can avoid saving the listener, and when needed just call getActivity() and then check if that object is "instanceof" Test, and if yes call it.

Answer (score 3):

You should probably set a [onBackStackChanged()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener) listener on your fragment manager.

Example:

```
getFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBackStackChanged() {

                //here you can check stuff. like:
                final Fragment mCurrentFragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container);

                //or get the number of fragments currently on your stack:
                getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() 
            }
        });
```

Comment: Although I do actually prefer the other answer, this would have worked